# Тип данных Char.Проверка старших и младших битов

Tags: c++, char, битовые-операции

У меня есть  переменная типа `char` и есть инструкция, по которой: если младшие 4 бита равны `0x0`, то это например буква `Q`, если `0x1`, то cимвол `+`. Аналогично с старшими 4 бита, если `0x0`, то это например cимвол `?`, если `0x1`, то это буква `R` и т.д.

Как организовать такую проверку?

Comment: `a & 0xF0 == 0` старшие (только значение 1 будет как 0x10) , `0x0F` - младшие

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заводим два массива символов: для старших и младших битов:

```
char high[] = { '?', 'R' ... }; 
char low[]  = { 'Q', '+' ... };
```

Получаем из исходного байта младшие и старшие биты и преобразовываем их в индекс:

```
unsigned char uc = c; // c - исходный байт
char hb = uc >> 4;    // старшие биты
char lb = uc & 0xF;   // младшие биты
```

Получаем искомые символы:

```
high[hb]; // символ из старших битов
low[lb];  // символ из младших битов
```

Comment: прошу прощения, не очень понял что здесь происходит, можете объяснить?

Comment: возможно я не совсем правильно объяснил. в моей инструкции нет последовательности. то есть, допустим, если старшие 4 бита 0xD, то это соответствует символу "+", если 0xF, то это соответствует символу "?", у младших например если  0xD то "P" , если 0xE то      "-",если,  0xF то "?". То есть по сути я хотел узнать как можно написать условно такое if (highbit==0x8) {char a = "R"} , мне не понятно как получить значение старшего и младшего бита

Comment: @bronstein87 допишите всё это в исходный вопрос путем его редактирования. Если нужно просто получить биты, то используйте `c & 0xF` для младших, `c >> 4` для старших. Вот и всё.

Comment: прошу прощения, что обращаюсь через столько времени, но только сейчас построил графики по тому, что получилось после разбиения char. Первую проверку делал таким образом if(((it->sp)>>4)==0x0) {high_sp_vec.push_back('A')и т.д . По итогам получилось, что в массиве почему-то не хватает 40 тысяч записей. Сто раз перепроверил, не нашёл опечатки, решил сделать вот так if(((it->sp)&0xF0)==0x00)
{high_sp_vec.push_back('A');} и все получилось правильно. Получается я всё-таки где-то проглядел опечатку или есть разница?

Comment: @bronstein87 сдвигаете (>>) `unsigned` переменную?

Comment: нет, но суть в том, что данные которые я обрабатывал изначально заданы как char и менять их нельзя

Comment: @bronstein87 их и не надо менять, просто перед сдвигом надо приводить к беззнаковому типу.

Answer (score 2):

Можно еще примерно так, через `union`:

```
typedef union {
    char  v;
    struct {
        unsigned char c: 4;
        unsigned char i: 4;
    };
} value;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    value v;
    v.v = 0x35;
    cout << char('A' + v.c) << endl;
    cout << int(v.i) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Битовые поля лучше не использовать, поскольку их порядок может зависеть от реализации компилятора. [1412 The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.1.html)